# How to display dropdown filters for posts

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I need to display posts by state and city filter. How can I do this?
By plugin? or by programming?

Here is an example of the layout

[image]

Comment: How are your state and city added? Are they taxonomies? Custom fields?

Comment: I thought about adding state and city by custom fields

Comment: Performance-wise it is much faster to query by taxonomy than custom fields (meta). Sounds like you need to do a little more research and set up the data first, and then share the code to receive assistance with filtering.